# How do I include multiple paragraphs as part of a single numbered entry in a numbered list?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document with a numbered list in it. Each entry was originally a single line, but as I have developed the document, I've decided that each entry needs additional explanation, and those explanations potentially run into multiple paragraphs.

I want to keep the numbering as it is. Word seems to assume that one number equals one paragraph. The only way I've found on my own to keep the numbering the way I want it is to individually number the "one-liners", and just format the entire collection to look as though it's a numbered list, without actually being one from Word's point of view. The problem with this is that I would have to manually renumber if I decide to rearrange the entries.

Is there a way to have a group of paragraphs treated as a single entry in a numbered list, with the number only appearing with the first paragraph?

Example:

```
1. Entry One, first paragraph

   Entry One, second paragraph

   Entry One, third paragraph

2. Entry Two, first paragraph

   Entry Two, second paragraph

3. Entry Three, only paragraph

4. Entry Four, first paragraph
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As one way of doing this, you may define the additional paragraphs
as bulleted. They will by default become sub-bullets of the previous
numbered paragraph, so left-align them by
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
The bulleted paragraphs will not affect the ordinals of the
numbered list.

Finally, change the bullet character to the blank character.

Here is how it will look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Quick and dirty:* You could use a manual line break at the end of the numbered line. (`Shift`+`Enter`). Then use `Enter` alone when you want a new number.

Alternatively, you could set it as a multi-level list with some levels not having a bullet. The full procedure for doing this is set forth by the late Word MVP Shauna Kelly in her page on [Controlling Bullets](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html). I would prefer this second method.

Comment: The problem with the manual line break is that it doesn't honor the inter-paragraph spacing, and it will forcibly justify the line that the break is on. For a casual document, this wouldn't be a problem, but this is for distribution in a context where I have to do it "right". It's likely that the multilevel list that you and @harrymc describe will end up being the method I use; I'll need to play around with it first, though.